# Убрать выделение ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли убрать выделение ToolStripMenuItem при  наведении и оставить только рамку?

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать свой [`Renderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer(v=vs.110).aspx) в котором переопределить отрисовку для выделенных пунктов :

```
class BorderOnlyToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Item;
        if (!item.Selected)
        {
            //если пункт не выделен, вызываем стандартную отрисовку
            base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
            return;
        }
        //в противном случае просто рисуем прямоугольник
        using (var p = new Pen(ColorTable.MenuItemBorder))
        {
            //возможно границы нужно будет подправить с учетом Padding
            var bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, item.Size);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width - 1, bounds.Height - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Затем применить его к меню:

```
menuStrip1.Renderer = new BorderOnlyToolStripRenderer();
```

Еще вариант: создать свою [таблицу цветов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable(v=vs.110).aspx) в которой переопределить (установить одинаковые) цвета для выделенных и невыделенных пунктов меню. Но в этом случае нужно будет ориентироваться на цвет фона каждого отдельного пункта меню.